# How to get the language chosen from the Application's settings in Android?

Tags: java, android, locale

I am trying to add the days in a calendar following what language the user chooses in the application settings (not the system).
I am in an Adapter and when I use mLocale, the application shuts down.

```
public static class DayOfWeekViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Context mContext;

    public DayOfWeekViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_calendar_header_date, parent, false));
    }

    public void setData(int dayOfWeek) {

        String mLocale = mContext.getResources().getConfiguration().getLocales().get(0).getLanguage();

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.now().minusDays(1);
        System.out.println("Test 1" + mLocale);
        date = date.plusDays(dayOfWeek);
        String dayText = date.getDayOfWeek().toString();
        String formatedDate =  date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE", Locale.forLanguageTag(Locale.getDefault().getCountry())));

        ((TextView) itemView).setText(formatedDate);
        itemView.setContentDescription(dayText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look likes your `mContext` is always null. If you post the crash log we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SharedPreferences`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

```java
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREF_FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("lang", "US_EN");
editor.apply();
```

Later you can retrieve it:

```java
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("PREF_FILE_NAME", MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.getString("lang", "DEFAULT_LANGUAGE");
```

I saved the name of my preferences file as a `String` in `res/values/strings`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from resources:

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
      return getResources().getConfiguration().getLocaleList().get(0).getLanguage();
   else
      return getResources().getConfiguration().getLocale().getLanguage();
```

Comment: Resources won't return the system Locale ?

Comment: no, they return application locale. You can change application locale and it can differ from system locale

Comment: It works but when I use it in my Adapter the app shuts dow.

Comment: And what's in crash log?